# Is this a correct proof of the Cantor-Bernstein-Schröder theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Sorry its a little messy. I haven't really cleaned it up yet.

Theorem: if $f:A\to B$ and $g:B\to A$ are injections, then there is a bijection from A onto B.

proof: Let $b \in B$. Since $g$ is injective, $g$ is invertible and $g^{-1}:g[B] \to B$ is bijective. Since $g^{-1}$ is bijective, it is onto, so $\exists x\in g[B] \subset A \mid g^{-1}(x)=b$. Since $x\in A$, $\exists y\in f[A] \subset B \mid f(x) = y$.

Let $R$ be a relation on $f[A]\times B$ such that $(u,v) \in R$ if $\exists w \in g[B] \mid f(w) = u$ and $g^{-1}(w)= v$. Suppose  $(q,p),(q,r)\in R$. Then $\exists m,n \in g[B] \mid f(m) = q, g^{-1}(m)= p, f(n) = q,$ and $g^{-1}(n)=r$. But $f$ is injective and $f(m)=q=f(n).$ Therefore, $m=n, p=g^{-1}(m)= g^{-1}(n) = r,$ and $R:f[A]\to B$ is a function.

So $R(y) =b$. Since $y\in f[A], \exists a\in A \mid f(a)=y,$ and since $R(y) = b,$ $R(f(a))=b.$ So, $R\circ f:A\to B$ is surjective.

Now let $(a,c),(b,c)\in R$. Then $\exists x,y \in g[B] \mid f(x)=a, g^{-1}(x) = c,f(y)= b,$ and $g^{-1}(y) = c.$ Since $g^{-1}$ is injective and $g^{-1}(x) =c =g^{-1}(y)$, therefore $x=y$. So $a=f(x)=f(y)=b,$ and $R:A\to B$ is injective.

Since $R$ and $f$ are both injective, $R \circ f:A\to B$  is injective. Since $R \circ f: A\to B$ is both surjective and injective, $R \circ f: A\to B$ is bijective $\Box$

Comment: Note: this is the [Cantor-Schröder-Bernstein theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6der%E2%80%93Bernstein_theorem).

Comment: "Constructive" is a notoriously hard thing to pin down and there isn't universal agreement on what it means even among constructivists.  But in general if you don't use proof by contradiction or disjunctive syllogism then you have a good chance of having what some would consider a constructive proof.

Answer (score 1):

The proof doesn't actually work. Let's take $A=B=\mathbb N_0$ and $f(n)=g(n)=n+1$.

We then have $g[B]=\mathbb N_+$, and we get
$$ R= \{ (n+1,n-1) \mid n\in \mathbb N_+ \}$$

The problem is now that even though this $R$ is a *function*, its domain is not all of $B$, but only $f[g[B]]$, which in this case doesn't include $0$ and $1$. So when you form $R\circ f$ there's nothing to match up with $(0,1)\in f$, so $(R\circ f)(0)$ is not defined, and so $R\circ f$ is not actually $A\to B$.

What $R\circ f$ actuall is is $g[B]\to B$, and $R\circ f$ actually equals $g^{-1}$.

We might try to patch that up by adding to $R$ all pairs $(b,b)$ where $b\in B\setminus f[g[B]]$. But that doesn't help us in this case, because then we'd have $(R\circ f)(0) = 1$ and $(R\circ f)(2)=1$, and $(R\circ f)$ then fails to be injective.

You need a more subtle idea to distinguish between elements where you use $f$ and elements where you use $g^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused by your answer. Mostly, though, I can't follow your example.

Now, I think R is f[A] -> B, and I know that every element in f[A] has a pre image in A. So shouldn't Rof:A->B?

Comment: @ZacharyF: You have defined that $(u,v)$ can only be in $R$ when $u$ is $f(w)$ for some $w\in g[B]$. So things in $f[A]\setminus f[g[B]]$ do not have an image under $R$. What do you think is unclear about my example?

Comment: notation. I don't know what N_0 and N_+ are. I also don't know what the \ means in B\f[g[B]]

Comment: @ZacharyF: $\mathbb N_0$ is $\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}$ whereas $\mathbb N_+$ is $\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$. The $\setminus$ is [set difference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SetDifference.html).